# Get repeated rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rows

Table1:

```
id  - name
1   - john
2   - david
3   - dilio
```

Table2:

```
id  - name
3   - dilio
7   - juan
1   - john
```

I want this result:

```
id  - name
1   - john
3   - dilio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select a.id, a.name
From Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: This will work fine assuming that the id numbers are what you want to compare - if it's names, you want to join on the name field (though it looks like id is what you want!)

Answer (score 1):

just use [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
Select a.id, a.name
From Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2
```

The natural join uses all column names that exist in both tables to match a pair of rows from these tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
ON Table2.name = Table1.name
```